# Issue with laravel blade for loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to print a table from an array. The content is printed if I just call my variable $listuser but when I try to print the content like $listuser['id'], its giving the following error

ErrorException
Trying to access array offset on the value of type int (View: ...../resources/views/admin/user-list.blade.php)

The code is as below

```
    <tbody>
                @for ($i = 0; $i < $listcount; $i++)
                @foreach($listusers[$i] as $key => $listuser)
                       
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{$listuser}}</th>
                    <td>{{$listuser}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><ul class="list-inline">
                      <li><a class="" title="delete" href="#" > <i class="bi bi-trash"></i></a></li>
                      <li><a class="" title="Edit" href="#" > <i class="bi bi-pencil-square
"></i>   </a></li></ul></td>
                  </tr>
                  @endforeach
                @endfor
```

Comment: Please, write your listusers and listcount array definations.

Answer (score 1):

```php
// just like this...
@foreach($listusers as $listuser)
    @foreach($listuser as $k => $user)
     
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it. However, it wasn't printing the data for each column. I had to use json_decode to print individual values.

Comment: you need to paste your original data and tell us what do you wanted.